# /30 IP block 4 - 3 useable IP

Tags: wide-area-network, draytek

I have 3 useable IP's?

This is what the ISP supplied. when I requested a IP block 4

- Gateway .232
- Router .233
- Spare IP .234
- Broadcast .235

How it is setup in the router.

Router picks up .233 as main IP. (has DCHP on currently)

.232 & .234 added as wan ip alias

They all can be pinged externally. I even did a test and swapped about port 80 between IP's to check you can access the same webpage from a external source.

[image: Image to IP setup]

From my understanding.

.233 is the IP the router should pick up from the ISP.
.234 is the spare IP Which I use for a SSL cert for our web application.

Hence as advertised by the ISP you only get 2 useable IP's.

Any advise on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you own /30 network and its last octet equals 232, then
232 - network address, unusable
233 - usable
234 - usable
235 - broadcast address, unusable

Comment: But the odd thing is .232 is usable!